# fetch and use data in batches using spring boot starter data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use JpaRepository of Spring Boot Starter Data JPA to create the repository like below.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository
        extends JpaRepository<CustomerData, CustomerKey> {

    String FIND_POPULATION = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXX WHERE OLD_CYCLE_CODE =  :cycleCode  ";

    @Query(value = FIND_POPULATION, nativeQuery = true)
    @QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1000"))
    public List<CustomerCycleHistoryData> findPopulation(@Param("cycleCode") short cycleCode);

}
```

This method is returning me a total of 100,0000 records.
I have used @QueryHints to fetch the data in batches with each batch of size 1000 records.

1. I don't know how it is creating batches.
2. If it is creating batches of the provided size then how can I access those batches because, in the end, it is returning me a list of 100,000 records and not List of data it retrieved in one batch.

I want the data it retrieved in batch because I am assigning it to a thread as a task. I don,t want 100,000 records together in one list.

Comment: You'll have to page it manually. Add a limit, order by the primary key, and add a where clause to fetch records greater than the last key returned.

Comment: there is no way to get it from spring data JPA?

Comment: JPA is an abstraction that has to deal with a _lot_ of underlying database implementations. `QueryHints` are just that: hints.

Comment: I have read about pagination also but in that, I have to maintain the count of pages and pass the page number explicitly to read data on a particular page. Is there any way that spring itself return me all the pages one by one and I don't need to provide the page number.

Comment: If you're using Spring, the spring-data-jpa library has `Page` and `Slice` abstractions.

Comment: Hi @AkshayaKAushik have you got the solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Raghawendrasingh yes, I found the solution in the Pagination and Filtering feature of spring boot. You can find many online examples for the same.